# Gala and Xorg high CPU usage on Lenovo X220

Tags: gala, battery, cpu, performance, xorg

[image: Top]

Gala and Xorg are always above 13%, even if there are no other windows except Terminator. It drains the laptop's battery and keeps the laptop's cooler always on.

I can't remember when I first noticed it, might be a month ago, or a couple of months. But it started bothering me now because of the cooler (probably the warm weather made it worse).

It's 0.4.1 Loki 64 bit, there are no updates available.

`uname -a
Linux blackbox 4.4.0-128-generic #154-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 25 14:15:18 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

PS: It's getting even worse when the screen is off due to inactivity. The screenshot below is made using an ssh session from another computer:

[image: 40%]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears, this is a known bug: https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/135

I added some shortcuts to Plank, rebooted the system and now everything is OK.